# OpenStreetMap PyQGIS error

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have a problem on the development of a python plugin, I'm trying to display the OpenStreetMap map behind layers, only the map is not synchronized with the layers, it can't find it or even the location.

The geographical position of the map does not correspond to that of my layers.

```
#Vlayer is defined above the code / Vlayer est définie au-dessus du code 

urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
maplayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([vlayer,maplayer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 690))

settings.setExtent(vlayer.extent())

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

render.start()
render.waitForFinished()

img = render.renderedImage()
img.save(QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()+"python/plugins/nro_print/img/render.png", "png")
```

result:

[image: resulut]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: can you clarify what is wrong with that map?

Comment: the geographical position of the map does not correspond to that of my layers

Comment: OK, where should you data be?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

 urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857' here I have given z x y of the map 

I can recover data this way 
vlayer.xMinimum
vlayer.yMinimum()
vlayer.xMaximum()
vlayer.yMaximum()

Comment: You say your data is in the wrong place, where should it be?

Comment: I'm saying that the geographical position of the map doesn't correspond to the geographical position of my layers. it should be exactly at the same position which one of my layers it will depend completely on the printed layer (it's never the same).

Comment: Maybe it's a CRS problem? Does your vlayer have a correct CRS? Can you also share (edit the question) the definition of the vlayer?

Comment: the crs is correct as the map is correct on qgis.Vlayer is the orange layer I want to synchronize with the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a destination CRS on the renderer settings. The following works for me.

Create a test memory layer

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4647&field=ID:integer(3)&field=value:double','test',"memory")

mypts = [QgsPointXY(32500000,5700000),
  QgsPointXY(32500010,5700010),
  QgsPointXY(32500010,5700060),
  QgsPointXY(32500040,5700090)
]

for p in mypts:
    pt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p)
    f = QgsFeature(vlayer.fields())
    f.setGeometry(pt)
    vlayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])

vlayer.updateExtents()
```

Add OSM layer, note `https` and `tile.`, not `a.tile.`.

```
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
maplayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
```

Define the settings, these are yours.

```
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([vlayer,maplayer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 690))
```

This is what I needed to set, otherwise the OSM layer wouldn't render. edit: Apparently, it needs to be the same as the vlayer CRS. This is also mentioned in [section 10.2 of the PyQIS cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#rendering-layers-with-different-crs).

```
settings.setDestinationCrs(vlayer.crs())

settings.setExtent(vlayer.extent().buffered(30))

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

render.start()
render.waitForFinished()

img = render.renderedImage()
img.save("c:/temp/render.png", "png")
```

Result, which is correctly placed

[image: result]

Full code [here as a GIST](https://gist.github.com/tilmanb/cb8621464adc9ab501fb2f85d6af4935).

Comment: Thank you very much I just added `settings.setDestinationCrs(vlayer.crs())` and it works perfectly